# Implementing NDAVI in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing

I am attempting to use the NDAVI index to segment emergent aquatic vegetation from open water. I read in a paper that this could be done.

```
var point = ee.Geometry.Point([-122.292, 37.9018]);

// Import the Sentinel-2 MSI image collection.
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2');

// Get the least cloudy image over the point in 2015.
var image = ee.Image(
  s2.filterBounds(point)
    .filterDate('2015-01-01', '2015-12-31')
    .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE')
    .first()
);

var ndavi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B2']).rename('NDAVI');

// Display the result.
Map.centerObject(image, 10);
var ndaviParams = {min: -.5, max: 0, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']};
Map.addLayer(ndavi, ndaviParams, 'NDAVI image');
```

This is my current code in google earth engine however when I run it I see no separation in open water between vegetation and water. Am I implementing this correctly?